# Questions About StackOverflow

Tags: support

1. I would like to edit a question to format it properly. How can I do that?
2. Do you get reputation for good edits?
3. How can I get a Moderator's attention? How does that system work?
4. How can I delete a closed question?
5. What if I can't get an adequate answer from StackOverflow?
6. Where can I ask questions about SuperUser?

Comment: As an aside: with regards to "corrections" by Eric, the names are actually Stack Overflow and Super User (words separated by space). See e.g. page titles (or the FAQ) on each site.

Comment: (Other than that detail, the edits were very useful of course)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I would like to edit a question to format it properly. How can I do that?**
You need 2,000 reputation to edit other's posts. If it is a community wiki, 100.

**Do you get reputation for good edits?**
No

**How can I get a Moderator's attention? How does that system work?**
Press Flag Button Under Question, Choose Option, Press Sumbit

**How can I delete a closed question?**
Press 'Delete' on your own question, or requires 10,000 rep for others.

**What if I can't get an adequate answer from StackOverflow?**
Place a Bounty after 2 days for at least 50 reputation. It will then become a 'featured' question, and whoever you pick as the accepted answer gets the reputation, and you get your answer. If you haven't picked an answer in 7 days, it auto accepts the highest voted answer.

**Where can I ask questions about SuperUser?**
Here (meta.stackoverflow.com)

For all other lovely Reputation Based Questions, refer to the [StackOverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Addendum about first point: if the question is in community wiki mode, 100 reputation suffices.

Comment: Added to answer.